# Swift and Cloud Firestore Transactions - getDocuments?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Transactions in Cloud Firestore support getting a document using transaction.getDocument, but even though there is a .getDocuments method, there doesn’t seem to be a .getDocuments for getting multiple documents that works with a transaction.

I have a Yelp-like app using a Cloud Firestore database with the following structure:
- Places to rate are called spots. 
- Each spot has a document in the spots collection (identified by a unique documentID).
- Each spot can have a reviews collection containing all reviews for that spot.
- Each review is identified by its own unique documentID, and each review document contains a rating of the spot.

Below is an image of my Cloud Firestore setup with some data.
[image]

I’ve tried to create a transaction getting data for all of the reviews in a spot, with the hope that I could then make an updated calculation of average review & save this back out to a property of the spot document. I've tried using:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
    let ref = db.collection("spots").document(self.documentID).collection("reviews")
    guard let document = try? transaction.getDocuments(ref) else {
        print("*** ERROR trying to get document for ref = \(ref)")
        return nil
    }
```

…

Xcode states:
Value of type ‘Transaction’ has no member ‘getDocuments’.
There is a getDocument, which that one can use to get a single document (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Is it possible to get a collection of documents in a transaction? I wanted to do this because each place I'm rating (spot) has an averageRating, and whenever there's a change to one of the ratings, I want to call a function that:
- starts a transaction (done)
- reads in all of the current reviews for that spot (can't get to work)
- calculates the new averageRating
- updates the spot with the new averageRating value.

I know Google's FriendlyEats uses a technique where each change is applied to the current average rating value, but I'd prefer to make a precise re-calculation with each change to keep numerical precision (even if it's a bit more expensive w/an additional query).
Thanks for advice.

Comment: Are you not able to just use getDocument() on each document you want to transact with individually?

Comment: Inside each "spot" document is a "reviews" collection. If a change has been made to a single review, I wanted to get all reviews, calculate a new averageRating, then save the new averageRating to the "spot".

Comment: Then you will have to query for all the reviews documents and transact with them individually.  You can't transact with just a collection id.

Answer (score 6):

1. No. Client libraries do not allow you to make queries inside of transactions. You can only request specific documents inside of a query. You could do something really hacky, like run the query outside of the transaction, then request every individual document inside the transaction, but I would not recommend that.
2. What might be better is to run this on the server side. Like, say, with a Cloud Function, which does allow you to run queries inside transactions. More importantly, you no longer have to trust the client to update the average review score for a restaurant, which is a Bad Thing.
3. That said, I still might recommend using a Cloud Function that does some of the same logic that Friendly Eats does, where you say something along the lines of `New average = Old average + new review / (Total number of reviews)` It'll make sure you're not performing excessive reads if your app gets really popular.